# How to register a DB failover callback in SOCI?

Tags: c++, soci

I connect to the database using the [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) library and I want to obtain database fail-over events for logging purposes. I'm not sure what interface to implement and how to do the callback registration. Is there such support in SOCI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only failover notifications supported by SOCI are for connections.

The `failover_callback` interface can be used as a callback channel for notifications of events that are automatically processed when the session is forcibly closed due to connectivity problems.

See the interface details at https://github.com/SOCI/soci/blob/master/docs/connections.md